# Symmetric function and it's derivates

Tags: calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a symmetric function, i.e., $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$. Is true that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a,a)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(a,a)$ for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$?

I try use the definition of partial derivative, but I have not success! Please, someone can help me?

Answer (score 3):

We have that
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a,a) = \lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(a+h,a)-f(a,a)}h = \lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(a,a+h)-f(a,a)}h = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(a,a)
$$
so yes!

Comment: Thanks. It's very easy!